# How to loop through API call with requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a script in python to loop through a list of lat/long coordinates and send each set through a boundary API call. I want to write each individual API response.

```
import json
import requests

coords = ['lat1, long1','lat2, long2','lat3, long3']

for x in coords:
    loc={'?contains':'x','&sets':'a_parameter'}
    response = requests.get('http://apicall.com/', params=loc)
    data = response.json()
    print data
```

I know that this is not the proper way to syntax the 'x' within the API call, but I cannot find documentation of a for loop including a requests API call.

Comment: What is your question? If you want to refer to `x` variable don't quote it. Are you wishing to group together lat-lng pairs of your list?

Comment: We need more information, what API, what do you mean by `syntax the x` ?

Comment: I am using the Tribune Boundary Service API (http://boundaries.tribapps.com/api/). @Jared The goal is to input the Lat Long and receive back the name of the neighborhood where that coordinate lies. I need to take each Lat Long "pair" and send it through the API call, the single quotes inside the coords list should accomplish this. My issue has been the response received. The API service keeps sending me the same information for each call b/c it is not recognizing the '?contains' parameter I am cycling through. I will try this without the quoted variable and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should remove **?** and **&** from '?contains' and '&sets' because they're not needed requests will do this for you, [check passing parameters in urls in the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
for x in coords:
    loc={'?contains' : x , '&sets' : 'a_parameter'}
    ...
```

This references the `x` variable, not the string `'x'`.